# Getting Selenium request, response

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

I tried the below code but req/response is not captured??

```
String trafficOutput = selenium.captureNetworkTraffic("xml");
selenium.type("q", "selenium rc");
selenium.click("btnG");
selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");

selenium.open("/#hl=en&source=hp&q=selenium+rc&btnG=Google
        +Search&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&fp=ff64793e1cab64b9");
selenium.click("//ol[@id='rso']/li[1]/h3/a/em");
selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
selenium.click("link=Selenium Core");
selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
selenium.click("link=our documentation");
selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
selenium.click("link=Projects");
selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
// assertTrue(selenium.isTextPresent("Results * for selenium rc"));

String resposneText = selenium.getHtmlSource();
DataOutputStream  dos = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("output", true));

System.out.println("value is-------- "+trafficOutput);
System.out.println("val is "+resposneText);

dos.writeBytes(trafficOutput);
dos.close();
```

But no req/response in this case?

Getting value for

```
System.out.println("val is " + resposneText);
```

Answer (score 1):

captureNetworkTraffic will return the traffic that has passed through Selenium Remote Control. When you call it you will get the log of traffic that has occured. This is probably what you want but if you want to be testing JavaScript it might be worth using something like jsTestDriver.

When you call getHTMLSource() it will return all the HTML that is on the page, or in the frame selenium is currently in, back to the test. You can then do other tests with the HTML.

Comment: problem is that output is empty and what if i want to capture all clicks request/response??

Comment: This sounds like you want to use Wireshark with your tests.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you still need an answer, but captureNetworkTraffic has to be called after you have done something. You have to do a selenium.start("captureNetworkTraffic=true") which will tell the server to start capturing, do all of your navigation and then call selenium.captureNetworkTraffic("xml"). Then you will have data, but from what I have seen it doesn't capture responses, just Requests.

Comment: but it doesnt give me for every click